# Connecting lines of radar chart in Tableau

Tags: line, tableau-api, radar-chart

So I have 7 variables I am plotting on a Tableau radar chart, I am following along this tutorial: https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/tableau-playbook-radar-chart. Where I have done the exact same calculations, instead of 6 axes, I have 7. Therefore 8 points in my path and dividing the Path equation by 7 instead of 6. I have also created the appropriate dummy variable in the Excel file, by duplicating the first variable and renaming it as a dummy variable to connect the line to. But still the last line does not want to connect.

Path field:

```
case [Variable]
when "ipsl_risicoperceptie" then 1
when "ipsl_onveiligheids-gevoelens" then 2
when "ipsl_vermijding" then 3
when "Ipersonenoverlast" then 4
when "Iverloedering" then 5
when "HICindex" then 6
when "HVCindex" then 7
else 8
end
```

Radian field:

```
IF [Path] = 8 THEN PI()/2
ELSE PI()/2 - ([Path]-1)*2*PI()/7
END
```

Rest of the fields are exactly the same as the tutorial. What am I missing?

[image: Tableau Screenshot]

Comment: The example linked has dual axis on the columns (X variable) and you have it on the rows. Not sure if that's the only issue.

Comment: Thanks for the input! The copied y axis is for labelling only. In the article you can see the writer achieves the full circle of lines with merely one X and one Y axis.